# How to restore a sql server 2014 .bak file when running sql servers 2012 and 2014 side by side

Tags: sql-server

I have both sql server 2012 and 2014 running on my windows 10 machine side by side. I am trying to restore a .bak file created in sql server 2014 on an another machine. When I try to restore it on my machine, it is complaining "Backup media verification failed" error. Due to some reason it is trying restore a sql server 2014 .bak file into sql server 2012 although I am using sql server 2014 
management studio to do the restore.

Thansk

Comment: It doesn't matter what version of SSMS you are running, it is about the server you are trying to restore it to. In your case it sounds like it is trying to restore to your 2012 instance.

Comment: You cannot restore a backup file from a newer version of SQL Server on an older version.

Comment: You are trying to restore backup from SQL Server 2014 instance to 2014 instance only right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade your sql server from 2012 to 2014, otherwise it will not allow you to do that due to the database version.

1. Backup your 2012 databases just incase
2. Either install new 2014 instance or upgrade your old 2012 instance to 2014.
3. Restore those backup files on the new 2014 instance, probably using `With move` command

Comment: I am running sql server 2012 and 2014 side by side

Comment: no matter how you run the sql server, Sql server does not support the old instance restore the newer version databases, that is the properties of the databases, only after the databases attached successfully to the older version of sql server, the database version will change. In your case, you have to get a 2014 new instance, or try to run everything on the old one again :(